# How to install libgdiplus on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, command-line, software-installation, yum

I need to install libgdiplus on CentOS 7. The application which I am running needs this package.

I was able to install it on Ubuntu, by using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdiplus
```

But when I run following command on CentOS, it says package not found.

```
sudo yum install libgdiplus
```

Answer (score 8):

You can search such packages using:

- `yum whatprovides libgdiplus`

The output shows: `libgdiplus-2.10-9.el7.x86_64 : An Open Source implementation of the GDI+ API`.

Then, you can run: `yum install -y libgdiplus-2.10-9.el7.x86_64`

As @Knud Larsen mentioned; you need to install `EPEL` packages repository previously. To do so, you can run:

`yum install -y epel-release`

Answer (score 2):

`libgdiplus` and `libgdiplus-devel` : Both are in the most commonly used extra repo for EL7 : epel.repo → "Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux"

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL → → https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-8.noarch.rpm'
```

Comment: IIRC Centos now ships with the initial Meta-RPM for EPEL, so `sudo yum install epel-release` should do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo yum install mono-complete -y
```